# Check if the record is unlocked in process builder or apex class?

Tags: apex, process-builder

I have a process builder with three decision nodes.

When a user is created , the process builder is fired and it assign different roles and permissions to the users.

The first decision is to assign the support ticket user . Next decision node is to assign the report folder manager to the user.  This is done from an apex class which is called from the process builder.

I am getting an error

> unable to The flow tried to update these records: null. This error occurred: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: group membership operation already in progress

This is happening because the first step (assigning the support ticket user ) is placing a lock on the record.

Is it possible to find out if the record is locked or not from the apex class?

Is it possible to check if one decision element is completed and record is unlocked  before proceeding to next decision in the process builder?

Thank you

Comment: @cropredy I'm not sure that Q&A is relevant to this one. They're not talking about an approval lock, rather an admin/share lock?

Comment: @sfdcfox -- you are right!

Comment: Creating a new question since the other one for approval process.

Comment: I tried creating a new question since the other one is for approval process. Can someone please let me know how to reopen this question?